# Rewrite rule to redirect query to directory in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm tring to redirect all the given id's from this url exemple :

`http://www.exemple.com/model.php?id=1234` or `http://www.exemple.com/model.php?id=2443`

(doesn't matter what id) to be redirected to

`http://www.exemple.com/model/1234` or `http://www.exemple.com/model/2443` (or any other given id's)

I have this code in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?model/([^/d]+)/?$ model.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Your rule is backwards, you're matching against the "to" instead of the "from".  

Use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to match and capture the part in the query string. Pretty basic and covered here: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we check the query string for the `id` parameter:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/model.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bid=(\d+)\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^model\.php$ /model/%1/? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Next, we want to match the digits appearing after `model` in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^model/(\d+)/?$ /model.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It is posible to show a 404 message for the deep path of this url ? Exemple : if someone access `http://www.exemple.com/model/1234/BLABLALBA/BLALBLA/ETC` to recive a 404 error or a redirect to first page ?